# Is it Metro app and Windows Store app same

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro

Is it Metro app and Windows Store app same

I want to develop metro app for run Windows Surface Pro and Windows Surface RT.

Metro app will run in both surface.So i want to develop metro app.

Is it Windows Store app is same as Metro App.

What are all things need to develop Metro App for run both surface pro and surface RT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Store is an application store for Microsoft Windows, starting with Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012. The platform can be used to provide listings for desktop applications certified to run on Windows, but is also the primary distribution platform for a new type of mobile app called **Metro-style apps** (common name) or **Windows Store apps** (official name).